# Executing JS calls during user login validation (Drupal 7)

Tags: javascript, users

I need to execute three different JS calls during the login process (for tracking reasons) depending on how the validation goes. I have no idea where to include them:

```
1. Event: Login failed (wrong password and/or user name)
-> wrong_pass();

2. Event: Incorrect E-Mail format (I am using E-Mail addresses as user names)
-> wrong_email();

3. Event: Login successful
-> login_ok();
```

How can I catch these events and react to them by executing the respective JS calls?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: using hook_user_login you can insert JavaScript snippet to call login_ok() when the login is successful, however dunno about other scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a validation hook to the user login form & block to add the javascript if the fields fail to validate.

So to alter the form:

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add the validate function
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_block' || $form_id == 'user_login') {
    // Add your javascript that contains Drupal.behaviors
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE_NAME') . '/MODULE_NAME.js');
    $form['#validate'][] = '_MODULE_NAME_user_login_validate'; // this is the function name
  }
}
```

Then in your validation function:

```
function _MODULE_NAME_user_login_validate($form, $form_state) {
  // Do your field validation here, I'll only showcase one of them (username)
  if(!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['name'])) {
    // Add a setting to the Drupal.settings variable available in javascript
    drupal_add_js(array('MODULE_NAME' => array('name' => FALSE)), 'setting');
  }
}
```

Finally in your `MODULE_NAME.js` file you can check to see if the setting was set:

```
if(Drupal.settings.MODULE_NAME.name == FALSE) {
  wrong_email();
}
```

Comment: Should note here that if you have other modules running a form_alter on the login forms, you may want to be cautious about the order in which they are executed.